# CSS font rendering at wrong size on small screen - Ionic 4 app - Android

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working on a mobile app using Ionic 4.

I am currently optimizing the app for small screens (currently using Unihertz Atom - 240x432 pixels).

The app displays great on standard sized phone screens but on this small screen font-sizes are not being rendered as defined by the css.  For example if I set an inline style font-size of 10px and view it in Chrome inspector I am seeing that the font-size is actually being computed to 13px:

[image]

This happens when the app is running on a real device.  If I use ***ionic serve*** and resize my desktop browser to match the small screen resolution it displays correctly.

Does anyone have any suggestions what might be causing this?

I have tried ***font-size-adjust: none;***  and ***font-size-adjust: 100%;***  but neither seem to make any difference to this issue.

**---- UPDATE**
If I set font-size to 2px it is computed at 10.6667px:
[image]

**---- UPDATE 2**
This isn't just happening to small font sizes - for example font-size 20px is computed as 26px:
[image]

Comment: 13 or 14px is some minimum for mobile browsers, 16px for input fields (iOS will zoom if font size is smaller). You gotta think some other ways to fit the content in... maybe to use images, scaling etc.

Comment: Hi, have you tried using a different scale "font-size: 0.8125em;" instead of  "font-size: 13px" for example?
 Some reading on the different scales and behaviours https://kyleschaeffer.com/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs-percent

Comment: Thanks @skobaljic - yes I thought that might be the case however if I set font-size to 10px it is computed to 13px - if I set the font-size to 2px it is computed to 10.666667px which suggests that 13px isn't the minimum size and that there is some scaling going on by the browser somehow... just not sure how to disable that

Comment: @BeavatronPrime - thanks for that.  yes I am using em and rem for all my sizing but am setting px while I try to figure out why the sizes aren't being calculated as I would expect